# array and assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly

If I declare these 3 arrays

```
int a[10][10];
int b[10][15];
int c[10][30];
```

For which of these three arrays, would the assembly code return the [i][j] element?  Assuming that the starting address of the array is stored in %ebx.

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
movl    8(%ebp), %edx          /* index i */
movl    12(%ebp), %ecx         /* index j */
movl    %edx, %eax
sall    $4, %eax
subl    %edx, %eax
addl    %ecx, %eax
movl    (%ebx,%eax,4), %eax
popl    %ebp
ret
```

How do you solve this type of questions

Comment: no im studying for my assembly midterm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this by doing some hand-written math with notes, such as this:

```
movl    8(%ebp), %edx          /* index i */
-> edx = i
movl    12(%ebp), %ecx         /* index j */
-> ecx = j
movl    %edx, %eax
-> eax = i
sall    $4, %eax
-> eax = 16 * i
subl    %edx, %eax
-> eax -= i, thus:
-> eax = 16 * i - i = 15 * i
addl    %ecx, %eax
-> eax += j, thus: 
-> eax = 15 * i + j 
movl    (%ebx,%eax,4), %eax
-> eax = array[4 * eax], thus:
-> eax = array[sizeof(int) * (15 * i + j)]
```

So, in `eax` at the end you get what's in the given array (pointed by `ebx` at the beginning) at position `15 * i + j`. This can properly address:

- An int array
- An array that has 15 for its first (right-most) dimension

Given that and your three arrays:

```
int a[10][10];
int b[10][15];
int c[10][30];
```

this addresses `b` properly, but not `a` nor `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards from the line that dereferences array:

```
movl    (%ebx,%eax,4), %eax
```

Here, `4*eax` is used as the offset (where 4 is `sizeof(int)`) so the value in `eax` is the number of `int`s from the beginning of the array. Now write an equation for `eax` in terms of the arguments read off the stack...